# How to set-up Random Board in WordFeud

Tags: wordfeud

How can I set up a random board in WordFeud? I just started playing, and my board is the traditional arrangement of tiles. I looked in my "settings" but didn't find an option for board set-up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In game options you can choose which board you wanna play in as you create a game.
Its the same place you choose which language your board should recognise.

[image] [image]